# iPhone issue with telerik app

Tags: iphone, cordova, telerik

When I focus on text box of hybrid telerik app in iPhone whole screen goes upsidedown. My fixed header position changes. Can anyone provide an explanation as to why this occurs?

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; 
document.getElementById('loginView').scrolling = 'no'; 
$("body").addClass("not_scroll");
```

Comment: can any one tell me what to do

Comment: Sumit, you don't ask a question. You don't format code as code but as quotation. You don't show an attempt to solve this yourself. In other words: **no**, no-one can tell you what to do, because you seemingly can't ask a question that actually is a question.